# IN query based on node id - Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, neo4j.rb

how,can i get the node details of the below id in optimized manner

```
 val = [2,4,5,6,34,32,34,54,54,31]
```

I tried as,

```
WITH [2,4,5,6, ..] AS coll UNWIND coll AS x
match p=(s....
return p
```

I cant able to get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MATCH (p:SomeLabel)
WHERE ID(p) IN [2,4,5,6]
RETURN p
```

should do it.